# AngularJS : Resolving promise objects based on value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I read in docs.angularjs.org that on a deferred object, a promise is resolved with a value and here are my couple of questions.

```
var dfd = $q.deferred();
```

1. `dfd.resolve()` - what happens when resolving without a value? Is it a rejection?
2. `resolve(value)` – *resolves the derived promise with the value. **If the value is a rejection constructed via $q.reject, the promise will be rejected instead*** what does it mean?

Can anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `dfd.resolve()` - what happens when resolving without a value? Is it a
>   rejection?

No, it's just the same as `dfd.resolve(undefined)` - you call a function with a parameter without arguments.

> `resolve(value)` "*If the value is a rejection constructed via
>   `$q.reject`, the promise will be rejected instead*" - what does it mean?

If the value is a promise, that promise's state will be adopted. `$q.reject` does construct a rejected promise. It'll work with fulfilled promises as well, like `resolve($q.when(value))`

Comment: Thanks.You clarified me.